# Running Out of Memory when reading a CSV file into an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, memory-management

I have a 26MB CSV file. Not huge but not small either. I am reading the entire file in with file_get_contents.

`$lines = explode(NEWLINE, file_get_contents($fname));`

The first row is headers so I use explode(',', $line) to turn the header line into an array of headers ($hdrs). From there I get rid of about 1/3 of the headers - they are values calculated from columns I'm keeping.

```
    $hdrs = explode(',', $lines[0]);
    foreach ($hdrs AS $key=>$hdr) {
      if (strpos($hdr, $srchStr) !== FALSE) { unset($hdrs[$key]; }
    }
    $hdrs = array_flip($hdrs);
```

So then I loop thru each line and process that line like this:

```
foreach ($lines AS $key=>$line) {
  $data = explode(',', $line);
  unset($lines[$key], $key, $line);

  // This maps the array from keys 0, 1, 2, ... to the header fields
  // It also eliminates any data fields not in the reduced $hdrs var
  $data = remap_data($data, $hdrs);

  // There are several line type and each line type has a subset of
  // the now reduced data that is important
  $type = determine_linetype($data);

  // Depending on the line type I eliminate even more data
  $data = further_reduce_data($data, $type);

  // Here I ave the data to an array; this is AdWords account data so I have ad
  // Campaigns at the top then Ad Groups then Keywords, ...
  // I use a switch to determine where the data should go into the array
  switch ($type) {
    case Keyword:
      $reducedData[$campaign][$adgroup]['KWs'][$kw] = $data;
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

This loop works as expected and organizes the data the way I want it. It eliminates the unnecessary data as well.

The test file I'm using has 72000 lines in it. About half way through the script runs out of memory. I can triple the memory available for the script, I have the RAM. However, I was under the erroneous impression that my unset of the lines as I used them as well as the elimination of more than half the data from each line would ultimately lead to the organized array using less memory not more than the fully loaded CSV file. Also, the memory used jumps by about 4.5 MB after this line `unset($lines[$key], $key, $line);` which makes no sense to me but I've tested it multiple times.

When I reduce the data in the $data array I do it by creating a var $output and saving all $data I want to keep to $output then returning $output from the function where it overwrites the original $data - i.e. `$data = reduce_data($data);`.

I've also tried casting all of these stings to their int, double, date, etc. This doesn't seem to make much difference either way.

Also, I save the reduced file every 1000 line processed using
`file_put_contents($fname, json_encode($reducedData));`

Like I said, this scripts bombs about half way thru. It looks like the json encoded text file of the re-organized data will be about 50% larger (despite having much less data) than the original. However, that still means a 40 MB file and the script is running out of memory after using more than 120 MB. (I could read the file 1 line at a time but then it would bomb 75% of the way thru instead of 50%.) And I assume that when I read in the json encoded file the resulting array would be quite large.

For now I can just bump up the memory I allow the script to use. However, I wanted to know what the PHP Gods had to say about why this is happening. Does an array really carry that much overhead? Is there a way to reduce it? Any best practices I should be following?

Comment: use fgetcsv http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php that way its not all loaded into memory, write to a temp file, then rename or what ever you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'd thought about reading it in one line at a time. However, the main problem is the amount of memory the array is taking up. I'm tempted to see if a simple object would take less memory but I doubt it. The problem is that I really do want the data organized into an easy to use array but that might not be possible without upping the memory the script is allowed to use.

Comment: @gabe I realize this is old, but do you recall ever finding a good solution to this?  I'm in a similar boat, where I'm dealing with a CSV file containing 40+ columns, and tens of thousands of rows of data.  Need to do several find/replace types of functions and working with it in an array is getting cumbersome.

Comment: @Mike Wish I could give you some advice. I've been coding in Python almost exclusively since about the time this question was written. Unfortunately, I don't remember the particular script I was addressing. Otherwise I'd go look at the code and see if there was something in it that I could add here.

Comment: @gabe No worries.  I ended up going away from the array route and instead dumped the data right into a csv output file.  Doesn't address a situation where you'd be working with a huge array, but it was a feasible solution for my specific scenario.